# Arch Linux , mount disks with thunar , without password

Tags: arch-linux, thunar, polkit

I just setup a minimal installation of Arch , installed gvfs , thunar-volman.

But mounting disk requires password , this shouldn't happen.

How should I work it out ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Arch Wiki has a section on the [udev page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Automount#UDisks) that covers the many ways you can set up automounting.

With a minimal install (without a DE), you can use a udev rule—there are several examples included on the page—or [udisks](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=udisks) and one of the wrappers like [udiskie](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udiskie), or something even simpler like [ldm](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=52272) that requires no other tools.

My preference is for udiskie and [the storage group](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udiskie#Storage_group).

Essentially, it is just a matter of starting udiskie in your `.xinitrc` and creating `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-udiskie.pkla`:

```
 [Local Users]
 Identity=unix-group:storage
 Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.*
 ResultAny=yes
 ResultInactive=no
 ResultActive=yes
```

Anyone in the `storage` group will now be able to mount and unmount devices.

Comment: It worked , but with latest arch linux , use `org.freedesktop.udisk2` instead

Comment: P.S: i just updated that wiki page on arch linux , thanks !